# subsonic 2.2 does not update nullable columns to null values

Tags: subsonic

When using the Update method on ODSController (ie using GridView / FormView in an ASP.NET application) and passing null values to nullable columns, the nullable column value remains unchanged.

This is due to the way that update method instantiate the ActiveRecord to update:

```
public void Update(Guid MyKey, ...)
{
    MyItem item =  new MyItem();
    item.MarkOld();
    item.IsLoaded = true;
    ...
    item.Save(UserName);
}
```

By creating an empty MyItem instance (all fields are null) and setting a nullable field to null doesn' t allow the column to finish in the DirtyColumns collection (see ActiveHelper GetUpdateCommand).

Am I going to have write custom update functions for EVERY table in my database to resolve this?

Comment: Never used that part of Subsonic, but flicking through the code, I think it's trying to compare the new and the old value to set the IsDirty flag, but I can't see anywhere it actually loads the old item??? Just as an experiment, could you try changing MyItem item =  new MyItem(); to MyItem item =  new MyItem(MyKey) and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Using MyItem item = new MyItem(MyKey) does fix the problem, it just strikes me that Subsonic is fundamentally flawed when you have to edit the auto-generated controllers just to make basic CRUD functions work. I've always been a big fan of Subsonic but issues like this just undermine my faith in it, it took days to isolate the problem. Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: Yeh, I guess it's one of those problems where only people using the ODS functions, who need to overwrite a nullable field would notice. If you're sure that's the fix, it's pretty easy to modify the templates so you don't have to manually change each controller. Let me know if you need any pointers on how to do this.